# Catching him with no commander trying to play cards- Risk

Tags: risk

It was year 5 and only two colours left on the board (myself and my brother). It was the last turn and his turn to go.

He had finished buying all his moon cards (at this time he had all his commanders except the nuke one). His first move was to play all his nuke cards, forgetting he had lost his commander, this meant he couldn’t win (the cards were his only chance).

I called him out after he tried to play the cards and told him he couldn’t play them if he didn’t have his nuke commander and couldn’t go back to buy it.

Should he have been able to go back and buy his commander which would have resulted in him winning the game, or should we have continued playing allowing him no commander?

Comment: You don't seem to be asking about the rules: you seem to know the rule. So instead you're asking about opinions one bending the rules and allowing take backs and such, right? As it is, there's no one answer for that.

Comment: Which version of risk is this?

Comment: I wouldn't call this a duplicate because it's an interesting variant of the issue: the player made illegal moves. In MtG, for example, this would actually change the answer significantly - if the illegal moves were discovered quickly (which they were), then the game is automatically rewound to before they happened and the player must choose different moves, which in this case would work out to his favor.